# How to install theme for Thunderbird 52 after Thunderbird 60+ was released?

Tags: thunderbird, themes

How can I install theme for Thunderbird 52 after Thunderbird 60+ was released? Is it possible?

I have just fresh install of Thunderbird 52 on my Windows 10 PC. When I go to `Options` > `Themes` and try to search for something - it returns me nothing. I was searching for ability to download theme but also found nothing. The [Thunderbird Themes](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/themes/) does not provide such functionality.

I want to use Thunderbird 52 because version of 60+ does not support addons which I use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the complete themes page in browser: 
   https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/complete-themes/?page=1
2. Hover over, shows the compatible versions of Thunderbird.
3. Rightclick on the DOWNLOAD button of the theme you want to instal, 'save link as', save to your device.
4. In Thunderbird,
5. go to addons page (Alt_T, addons)
6. click on the cog at the top of the page, install addon from file.
7. navigate to your downloaded addon, click on it.
   Thunderbird may ask to restart
   Done!